# Azure Linix VM dns-search

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, azure

New to Azure and trying to understand DNS resolution for Linux guests.

My VNET is set to two Windows DNS servers in Azure, when I add a Linux VM they are present and I can ping IP addresses and FQDN's in Azure and on-premise across the VPN.

So at the moment:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 - works
ping hosta.mydomain.com - works
ping hosta - does not work
```

Traditionally I get the last to work either via adding dns-search to interfaces or resolv.conf, but these are overwritten by Azure each reboot.

I have found that if I add the line

```
dns-search mydomain.com
```

to **/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg** it works.

I am unsure if this is best practice as I have also seen this article "[Azure Linux VM name resolution](https://serverfault.com/questions/688393/azure-linux-vm-name-resolution/688823#688823)" suggest it should be done via **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**.

Is someone able to advise what the best way to do this is, one that survives reboots and preferably survives changes at the Azure portal NIC blade?

Cheers

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

Answer (score 1):

When you reboot your VM, Azure VM waagent will rest `/etc/resolve.conf` file, so you will find the file is overwritten.

As S.Walker's [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-using-your-own-dns-server), you could use custom DNS server. You could do it on Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: If it works, please don't forget to accept it as an answer. It will help more people in the community.